# c++ max choosing sort

Tags: c++, sorting, syntax

I have started to learn c++. (I learn applied maths at school) And I must learn programming. I have just wrote a max choosing sort in c++. It should print the elements of a predefined array in decreasing order, but it is not working. Can you tell me where did I go wrong?

```
int* max(int *array)
{
    int *max = array++;
    while(*array)
    {
    if (*max<*array) *max = *array;
    array++;
    }
    return max;
}

void change (int *what, int *to)
{
int *temp = what;
what =to;
to = temp;
}

void sort(int *array)
{
while(*array) change(array,max(array));
array++;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int A[] ={7,5,6,9,2,5,3,1,4,10,6,7,2,8};

    sort (A);
    int i =0;
    while (A[i]) cout<<A[i++];

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, that's hardly C++...

Comment: How is it not working? Crash?  Invalid output?  Some error message you don't understand?

Comment: @KerrekSB it's perfectly valid C++.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: depends on your definition of C++.  The standard entry point is called `main`, not `_tmain`.  It's hardly *standard* C++.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem I see is that `while (*array) { ... }` won't terminate where you want it to because what is beyond the last element of your array is not certain to be 0 or NULL, or it may terminate in the middle of your array if you are sorting an array that includes 0.

Instead you want to say something like:

```
int A[] = { ... };
int element_count = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < element_count; ++i) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have the concepts of pointers and values reversed. For example, your `change` function, as it is now, is

```
void change (int *what, int *to)
{
    int *temp = what;
    what =to;
    to = temp;
}
```

when it should be

```
void change (int *what, int *to)
{
    int temp = *what;
    *what = *to;
    *to = temp;
}
```

Which is almost exactly the opposite.

There are also several misuses of pointers in the `max` function that I can see as well as the `sort` function, and that is what I see after only a very brief glance at the code. You need to go back and learn pointers, and then try this again.

Answer (score 2):

The second problem is that the `array++;` in the `sort()` function is not part of the while loop.    I wouldn't be suprised if this never exits.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to explicitly show what you're trying to do by using the right type; for example:

```
while (*array)
{
    ...
}
```

would be a lot easier for you to debug if it said something more like

```
while (array != NULL)
```

or even

```
for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    // do something with array[k]
}
```

Also, your `change` function seems like it should swap two values that the pointers point to, but it doesn't.

Just in case it helps, I think the technical name of what you're doing is called "[Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)". This might help if you need to ask anyone else for advice!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all. Actually I was trying to learn pointers through this. And called it max choosing sort because I translated it word by word from Hungarian.

Comment: Cool! I always find it easiest to learn the simple ways to do things (like using a for loop to go through a list) and then translate strange hack-y ways into the equivalent "easy" way in my head.